# Doctrine unable to get instance from request information

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have been trying different methods to get entity attributes from twig and use them in the controller to insert in another database table.
The idea here is to get the attributes of the twig table as an already existing database variables and insert them into another table on button click and it does not seem to work for me and after trying several methods I find myself stuck with doctrine not recognizing the attributes I pass in the controller as parameters, I would highly appreciate some help here because somehow it does not make sense anymore.
This is the twig in which I send the parameter ID from the html table :

```
 <a href="{{ path ('addConte',{'$id':contes.idconte}) }}">Ajouter</a>
```

Here is the function that should use that parameter in order to populate another table with the entity instance having that ID, actually I made 2 functions that should do the same thing and none of them works, instead they return the same doctrine exception,
This is the first function :

```
/**
     * @Route("/ajout/{$id}", name="ajouter")
     * @param Contes $id
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function ajouter(Contes $id)
    {
        $lstContes1 = new Inventairecontes();
        $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Contes')->find($id);
        $lstContes1->setTitrec($em1.titre);
        $lstContes1->setAuteurc($em1.auteur);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($lstContes1);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Conte ajouté avec succées!');
    }
```

and this is the second function that should populate a form before inserting into the database :

```
/**
     * @Route ("/add/{$id}", name="addConte")
     * @paramConverter ("idCc", options={"mapping":{"id":"idc"}})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function add(Contes $idCc, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Contes')->find($idCc);
        $form = $this->createForm(Inventairecontes::class,$em);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form -> isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
           $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
           return $this->redirectToRoute('listeContes');
        }
        return $this->render('liste_contes/add.html.twig',[
            'em'=>$em,
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

I really hope someone could provide some help and thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand everything in your code, but at first sight, I see that.

Usually, parameters in twig path function don't use the dollar sign.

```
<a href="{{ path ('addConte',{'id':contes.idconte}) }}">Ajouter</a>
```

The same is true in route annotation and your $id parameter is of type Contes.

I think what you are trying to do is.

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajout/{id}", name="ajouter")
 * @param Contes $contes
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function ajouter(Contes $contes)
{
    $lstContes1 = new Inventairecontes();
    $lstContes1->setTitrec($contes->getTitre());
    $lstContes1->setAuteurc($contes->getAuteur());
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($lstContes1);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Conte ajouté avec succées!');
}
```

If your Contes Entity has a property `id` it will automatically get the matching Contes using the magic of param converters.

Next, here I see many problems.

1. @ParamConverter annotation should use a capital P
2. I don't know what is the idCc argument, but the first argument should be an entity
3. Looks like you are trying to map the id property of idCc to an idc parameter that is not in your @Route

Maybe you should give more details because I really don't understand that part.

```
/**
 * @Route ("/add/{id}", name="addConte")
 * @paramConverter ("idCc", options={"mapping":{"id":"idc"}})
 * @return Response
 */
public function add(Contes $idCc, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Contes')->find($idCc);
    $form = $this->createForm(Inventairecontes::class,$em);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form -> isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('listeContes');
    }
    return $this->render('liste_contes/add.html.twig',[
        'em'=>$em,
        'form'=>$form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

More info [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrineconverter-options).

Comment: I tried to fix the first function you way you did it and now it does not recognize the variable "titre" and "auteur" that I use to set the new ones with, he cannot read the object "$contes.titre" and "$contes.auteur"

Comment: What version of symfony are you using?

Comment: 4.4.21,The exception now says the following : Use of undefined constant titre - assumed 'titre' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Oh boy, I think I was tired, I updated my answer

Comment: it worked finally !!! thank you so much for saving me haha, it has been 2 and a half day now. Many thanks